# how to define and use multiple sockets in python

Tags: python, sockets

I want to make a server, which receives messages from smartphones and based on them, sends messages to one specific IP and port. but when I define two IPs (one for the server and another to send messages) gives the error that I cannot use the socket more than ONE time. I am not a programmer, so please help me correct my code.

```html
import socket
import time

host = '192.168.100.41' #Define a server to receive messages
port = 5000

s = socket.socket()
s.bind((host,port))

s.listen(1)
c, addr = s.accept()
print ("Connection from: ")
while True:
    Buffer = c.recv(1024)
    if not data:
        break



address = ( '192.168.100.60', 5555) #Defind Destination address to send a message (must match destination IP and port)
client_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM) #Set Up the Socket
client_socket.settimeout(1) #only wait 1 second for a resonse


def ON(evt):
    data = "1ON" #Set data
    client_socket.sendto(data, address) #send command
    try:
        rec_data, addr = client_socket.recvfrom(2048) #Read response
        print (rec_data) #Print the response
    except:
        pass
```

Comment: Could you just use a different port for each socket?

Comment: I am not sure, I just want to receive messages from different clients(android smartphones) and based on them, send proper messages to one IP on the internet(to a UDP and microprocessor) the code structure is not important for me.